# Bigcommerce API product images

Tags: php, python, api, bigcommerce

I am able to upload products to my Bigcommerce store via the API with no problem, but I want to link those products to images that I have already uploaded via WebDav-the images are currently in the 'upload' folder. How do I do this?

When I upload products via a CSV file, all I do is have a column labeled 'Product Image File', which contains the file name of the image that is residing in the 'upload' folder. When products are created this way, Bigcommerce will automagically link the products with the associated images.

End goal is to use the API for product creation, and tell Bigcommerce which image file to use that has been uploaded via WebDav, in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main thing to note in regards to adding images via API is that it must be done in a separate request from the creation of the product, unlike when importing by CSV. Your script should first create the product and capture the ID of the newly created product from the response BC gives you. Once you have that ID you can add an image by following the "create a product image" POST method described on this page:

https://developer.bigcommerce.com/api/stores/v2/products/images

### You can only add one image per POST request.

The full path to the image (including http://) will be added to the **image_file** parameter of the object you pass in your POST request body.  This is the only parameter that must be passed when creating an image but there are other things you can pass along as well if you choose.

If the images that you have uploaded to the Webdav server of your store are placed into the **/product_images/import/** folder then you can reference the image in the **image_file** parameter by just the name of the image with it's extension (ie: image_name.jpg) just like in a CSV import.  You stated that you uploaded your images to an 'upload' folder though, if that is the case you *must* use the full HTTP path to the image.

Answer (score 0):

The image file path has to be relative to the 'import' directory:

https://developer.bigcommerce.com/api/objects/v2/product_image

> When specifying a product image, the image_file should be specified as
>   either: A path to an image already uploaded in the import directory
>   and the path should be relative from the import directory or a URL to
>   an image accessible on the internet.

Comment: please be more specific. What is the relative path to import directory? Spell it out for me. @user2300870

Comment: For completeness - the relative path to the import directory is:

`/product_images/import/`

Answer (score 0):

the same problem I was facing, i was trying to upload an image in a product using V3 API,  but show errors 422 "image URL must be preset if uploading image by URL", my image is present in WEBDEV server,

file path: `/dav/product_images/import/abc.jpeg`

I was trying to upload an image URL  with API Body

```
{

 "description": "Top View upload",

 "image_url": "https://store-xxxxxxxxxxxx.mybigcommerce.com/dev/product_images/import/abc.jpeg",

 "is_thumbnail": true,

 "sort_order": 1

}
```

it was showing error,

so I download Cyberduck to connecting to my WebDAV server, I create a connection

`https://support.bigcommerce.com/s/article/File-Access-WebDAV`

after connecting my store server with Cyberduck, I open folder   "product_images/import/abc.jpeg"

then  right-click on  and click on "Open URL" copy URL and paste it in API image_url value

Issue: please use the following URL structure if upload image URL from Webdev :

https://store-url/product_images/import/image_name.jpg

Eg. https://store-abcdefghijk.mybigcommerce.com/product_images/import/abcd.jpg

i was using the wrong path i.e.

https://store-abcdefghijk.mybigcommerce.com/dev/product_images/import/abcd.jpg

if you are using dev in the image URL please remove it